# How to view extra large images?

Tags: files, image-viewers

I just downloaded [this file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Pieter_Bruegel_the_Elder_-_The_Tower_of_Babel_%28Vienna%29_-_Google_Art_Project_-_edited.jpg) and I cannot open it with the default Image Viewer because it crashes without opening the image; is there any other way to open very large images?

I have 6GB of ram so this 200MB+ image should be opened without issues.

Comment: Here is what I see when I try to open it from the command line with eog: 'Error interpreting JPEG image file (Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x3c 0x21).'

Comment: I use Firefox for images that are too big for the Eye Of the Gnome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The image size is over 200MB.  I downloaded, and tried to open with image viewer, and it won't open.  I opened with Gimp, and it works fine.  See below

[image]

Comment: What Gimp version do you have? I used Gimp version 2.8.10

Comment: that is a beautiful image by the way

Answer (score 5):

All image viewers I tried, except "Gnome Image Viewer" worked fine opening that image:

- `geeqie` < imo, this one is by far the best image viewer
- `gthumb`
- `shotwell`
- `feh`

And it works also fine in other software that is not specialized in viewing images

- `gimp`
- `firefox`
- `qgis`

Sometimes, the Gnome software has much better alternatives (e.g. `gedit` is the same, very slow for big files).

Comment: Alright I'll fix that.

Comment: Out of all these programs, only firefox was abole to display a 50k x 50k PNG and 100k x 100k PNG. (idk how to use qgis). gimp in particular uses a huge amount of memory for the purposes of image editing.

Answer (score 4):

The image opens perfectly fine in Shotwell Photo Manager (version 0.22.0) on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
[image: Shotwell Screenshot]

Alternately, you can try out ImageMagick(Q16) image editor.